# Ble pairing in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I wanted to pair android device  with a ble device in my app.but whenever i call createbond () after connecting to the ble device,i get reply a like pairing rejected or pairing failed due to incorrect passkey/pin.but im not even asked to enter a pin.?please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it outside the app before? Like did you use the Android example App / Guide? I had similar issues and solved them all with this Website

[Android Bluetooth LE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

and here the example Project:

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html

After it is working with that app you can try implement it to yours.